# I can't prove it $\max\{P( A \cup B^c ), P(A \cap B) , P (A \Delta B )\}\geq \frac{1}{5}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

1.) $\max\{P( A \cup B^c ), P(A \cap B) , P (A \Delta B )\}\geq \frac{1}{5}$

2.) $P(AB)^2 + P(AB^c)^2+ P(A^cB)^2+P(A^cB^c)^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}$

Can anybody help? I tried with this  $P(A)=P(A)- P(AB)$ and it wouldn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Let us give the following names to the probabilities associated with the partition of $\Omega$ induced by $A$ and $B$:

$$x=P(A \cap B^c), \ y=P(A \cap B), \ z=P(B\cap A^c)$$

Then the first inequality amounts to

$$\max(1-z, \ y, \ x+z) \geq \frac{1}{5} \ \ \ \text{knowing that} \ \ \ 0\leq x,y,z\leq 1 \ \ (1)$$

Let us assume that (1) is false. We would have

$$\begin{cases}1-z &< &\frac{1}{5}\\y&<&\frac{1}{5}\\x+z&<&\frac{1}{5}\end{cases}$$

Adding the 3 inequalities, one would obtain $1+x+y<\frac{3}{5}$ which is impossible because $x$ and $y$ are $\geq 0$.

Remark: it looks odd that the minimum $\frac{1}{5}$ is not "tight". One could have taken $\frac{1}{3} \cdots$

Edit: With the same conventions, the second inequality deals with

$$q=y^2+x^2+z^2+(1-x-y-z)^2 \ (2)$$

We have to prove that $q \geq \frac{1}{4}.$

In (2),  $x=P(A)$ and $z=P(B)$ play a symmetrical rôle (because our issue is symmetrical:  sets $A$ and $B$ are interchangeable). Thus the minimum value of $q$ must occur when $x=z$.

Replacing $z$ by $x$ in (2), it suffices to consider the minimal value of:

$$q'=2x^2 + y^2 + (1 - y - 2x)^2$$

$q'$  can be written under the Gauss form (see for example http://www.tricki.org/article/Complete_the_square):

$$q'=\frac{2}{3}(3x + y - 1)^2 + \frac{1}{12}(4y - 1)^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$

proving that $q' \geq \frac{1}{4}$.

Remark: This minimum is reached when the content of the 2 parentheses is 0, i.e., for $x=y=\dfrac14$. This time, the minimum is tight...